# How to view local changes by date in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, history

How can I view changes made in the whole workspace on a specific date in Eclipse? Is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Right Click` on the file and select `"Compare With" > "Local History"`.

It will list the file history by date. Click on any date will display the history of the file content with current version.

This is what Eclipse supports about local history

[Local history in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm)

Comment: But this work for one file, I want to check whole workspace (more then 20000 files)

Comment: @AndrzejKasp: Your system will crash if you tried to do so by any other way., I'm not sure why you would need that

Comment: I need to check all changes made by my mate when I was out

Comment: @AndrzejKasp: Not sure in Eclipse, But diff command might be useful for  you.

Answer (score 2):

To view the resource history for a file:

1. Select the file in one of the navigation views. From the context
   menu, choose Team > Show History.
2. The History view will open and show a history for the selected CVS
   file.

> Note: The History view also shows you all version and branch tags that
>   are associated with the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SCM(SVN or GIT etc) to see the list of changes on your workspace. Thus you can synchronize the local workspace with the remote repository to see the list of changes.

There is no eclipse built in way to do this. However you can check the local history of a single file as answered by @Laxmikant Gurnalkar.

Also note that you can create local repositories in GIT and SVN.